Graphene dispersion at Dirac points
After deriving the dispersion relation of graphene:
$$ E(k) = \pm t \sqrt{3+2\cos{(k_y \sqrt{3} a)} + 4\cos{\bigg(\frac{3a}{2} k_x \bigg)} \cos{ \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a k_y \bigg)} } $$
how do I see that the energies are degenerate at the Dirac point $K = (4 \pi/3a, 0, 0)$? When I plug this in, I just get:
$$ E(k) = \pm t \sqrt{3+2+4}$$
which is certainly not degenerate. What am I misunderstanding here? Thanks!

The Wikipedia page has $E(k)=\pm\gamma_0\sqrt{1+4\cos^2(a k_x/2)+4\cos(a k_x/2)\cos(ak_y\sqrt{3}/2)}$, which actually does give $0$ for $k=({\large\frac{4\pi}{3a}},0)$.

But my dispersion relation matches what is given in this Review paper on graphene: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.109

Strange indeed... See pictures in added answer.

I changed the answer, now it includes a reasonable explanation!

The Wikipedia page about graphene's [electronic properties] has a different expression for the energy bands:
$$
 E_1(k) = \pm\,\gamma_0\, \sqrt{1+4\cos^2\frac{ak_x}{2}
  +4\cos\frac{ak_x}{2}\,\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}\ ak_y}{2}} \tag{1}
$$
which actually does give $E(k) = \pm 0$ for $k=({\large\frac{4\pi}{3a}},0)$. If we plot the square root part of the Wikipedia result we get this: (with the green sticks marking the zeroes)

And if we plot your result
$$
 E_2(k) = \pm\,t\, \sqrt{3+2\cos\,\sqrt{3}\ ak_y
  +4\cos\frac{3ak_x}{2}\,\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}\ ak_y}{2}} \tag{2}
$$
which is apparently also the result from [RevModPhys.81.109] we get the following (for $t=1$), where we see 10 instead of 6 zeroes and the hexagonal pattern is smaller and $30^{\large \circ}$ rotated:

There seems to be a different choice of basis (and scale). You can convert $(1)$ into $(2)$ by using: (if we assume $t=\gamma_0$)
$$
 E_2(k_x,k_y) = E_1(\pm\sqrt3\, k_y, \pm\sqrt3\, k_x)
$$
and of course the degeneracy in $E_2$ is now at $(k_x,k_y)=(0,{\large \frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt3 \,a}})$

just adding to the answer above:
you also need to be careful with conventions of the unit cell because this will affect the BZ and the position of the K points.
there are 2 main conventions I'm aware of:

2 vertices of the real space hexagon are on the x axis leading to 2 vertices on the ky axis

2 vertices on the y axis leading to 2 vertices on the kx axis.


I believe your original dispersion relation is in the second convention and the Wikipedia page in the first one.
To see the difference yourself I suggest you try to derive the dispersion relation from a tight binding model:

write down the tight binding hamiltonain (I suggest to do it in bra-ket notation)
perform discrete fourier transform (this is where the different conventions will differ- the hopping vectors will be different)
you will get an expression you can write as a vector-matrix-vector multiplication:
(|k,A>,|k,B>)H (<k,A|, <k,B|)^T
finally the energy you will get from the determinant of the Bloch hamiltonian

hope that helps clearing up the confusion
Edit:
I saw new the edit of the answer above- I think we see 4 "extra" degeneracy points because the plot goes beyond the first BZ.
